# Output a fixed leg number in a TextView - Android

Tags: java, android

I need to print a number in a TextView that must have a fixed dimension.

For example:

- I've an Int value of 15, in my TextView I shoud have 00000015.
- I've an Int value of 15125, in my TextView I shoud have 00015125.

Something like add 0 to have always a text with 8 numbers.

Can you advice me an efficent way with small code to do this?

Comment: Have you tried at all? It shouldn't be too difficult to go ahead and give an attempt then post what you have here if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.format("%08d", yournumber);
```

for zero-padding with length = 8.  Ypu may Find more way to do so  [java.util.Formatter Class Detailed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
int value = 15125;
String textViewText = String.format("%08d", value);
textView.setText(textViewText);
```

`%08d` padds 8 zeros (at most) in front of your integer value;